# I cannot fix this bug Cannot invoke 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '(([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)'

Tags: swift

I tried follow many posts on Stackoverflow and Google, but anything is true.
So I need help to resolve this bug, thanks

My code is using parse api

```
func LoadData(){
    Timeline.removeAllObjects()

    var FindTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Twitter")
    FindTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            for object in objects{
                let Twitter:PFObject = object as PFObject
                self.Timeline.addObject(Twitter)
            }
            let Array:NSArray = self.Timeline.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.Timeline = NSMutableArray(array: Array)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is looking for objects and error to be optional, as they may be nil. Try:

```
FindTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects: [AnyObject?], error: NSError?) -> Void in ...
```

Comment: It come to new bug  '[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator' ?

Comment: I may have the optional in the wrong place in that case, it's the array elements that may be nil. So [AnyObject?]